# encrypt file with BouncyCastle , output look corrupted

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pgp

so i using this code to encrypt my file

as you can see iam using public PGP

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.2.6 (GNU/Linux)

masdSFVkRBADYxPZYC+nu9nhSVkxcVkVJ5axZKzCRuygqUxka
kZIBy2CAQVKz5dBkRaUkaaksbcyautks7asaov26Fc9cT25Rvnh7
wYIJhcRoIl4cxashdgutasd0qfcOnVB5JVCQDhXclBW7kwCgkoUW
....
...
...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

the code works fine but i think the data of the encrepted file is corrupted

because it doesnt comes out in this format (like the key)

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.2.6 (GNU/Linux)

masdSFVkRBADYxPZYC+nu9nhSVkxcVkVJ5axZKzCRuygqUxka
kZIBy2CAQVKz5dBkRaUkaaksbcyautks7asaov26Fc9cT25Rvnh7
wYIJhcRoIl4cxashdgutasd0qfcOnVB5JVCQDhXclBW7kwCgkoUW
....
...
...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

am i wrong?

dont the output should be in the same format ?

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Text;

using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg;

class CPGPencrypt
{
    private static PgpPublicKey ReadPublicKey(Stream inputStream)
    {

        inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);

        PgpPublicKeyRingBundle pgpPub = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);

        //
        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real
        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
        //

        //
        // iterate through the key rings.
        //

        foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in pgpPub.GetKeyRings())
        {
            foreach (PgpPublicKey k in kRing.GetPublicKeys())
            {
                if (k.IsEncryptionKey)
                {
                    return k;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptFile(byte[] clearData, string fileName, PgpPublicKey encKey, bool withIntegrityCheck)
    {

        MemoryStream bOut = new MemoryStream();

        PgpCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(
            CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);

        Stream cos = comData.Open(bOut); // open it with the final destination
        PgpLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();

        // we want to Generate compressed data. This might be a user option later,
        // in which case we would pass in bOut.
        Stream pOut = lData.Open(
            cos,                    // the compressed output stream
            PgpLiteralData.Binary,
            fileName,               // "filename" to store
            clearData.Length,       // length of clear data
            DateTime.UtcNow         // current time
        );

        pOut.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);

        lData.Close();
        comData.Close();

        PgpEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, new SecureRandom());

        cPk.AddMethod(encKey);

        byte[] bytes = bOut.ToArray();

        MemoryStream encOut = new MemoryStream();
        Stream os = encOut;

        Stream cOut = cPk.Open(os, bytes.Length);
        cOut.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);  // obtain the actual bytes from the compressed stream
        cOut.Close();

        encOut.Close();

        return encOut.ToArray();
    }

    public static string Encrypt(string file_name,string file_to_read)
    {


        try
        {

            byte[] dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file_to_read);
            Stream keyIn = File.OpenRead("pgpdata-public.asc");
            Stream outStream = File.Create(@"myfolder\"+file_name);
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptFile(dataBytes, @"myfolder\"+file_name, ReadPublicKey(keyIn), false);
            outStream.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
            keyIn.Close();
            outStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
        return file_name;

    }


}
```

Comment: What are you getting right now as the output?

Comment: somethig like that 
´îØK‘ó*Dò+Uþ¢Uûµ"ÍG×H ‚…ø IªvvOõ–ËEAë¹™ÅO3hšÀÅýØ¦¿º<H€itOŒ^ÏU…ž]ë¹Þ¾.X_èüD_…õÐ‚O–¤Ó

Comment: You're encrypting a file and the data is being compressed and output as binary. Why are you expecting it to look like a plaintext signature block?

Comment: i dont know why, its the first time iam encrypting files
can u tell if this output is logic...

Answer (score 1):

There are **different encoding schemes** in OpenPGP, namely

1. binary data and
2. ASCII armored data.

Especially for key exchange, normally the ASCII armored format is preferred as it is more robust and easy to recognize. For mail exchange, it is mandatory (for 7 bit compatibility). The binary version also has advantages, especially regarding performance and storage (bandwith) requirements.

For example, GnuPG will use the binary encoding by default, unless you request the ASCII armored version using the option `--ascii` or abbreviated `-a`.

**It look like your code is outputting the binary encoding, but works all fine.**

You can easily test by **trying to decrypt** (eg. using GnuPG: `gpg --decrypt file.pgp`). Alternatively, you can **dump the OpenPGP packets** the file contains by using `gpg --list-packets file.pgp` or using the more verbose utility `pgpdump`, which is available in most (unix) package repositories: `pgpdump file.pgp`. Unlike `gpg --list-packets`, it also resolves packet and algorithm identifiers to human readable strings (where `gpg --list-packets` just dumps their numeric IDs).

Comment: ok
this is my options 

Binary,

 Text,
 utf8

what's mat ch to ASCII armored data ? 

Text

Comment: Binary is binary (what you observed above). ASCII armored text is "readable" plain text (at least its header) and otherwise will only contain ASCII characters. There are only these two choices for OpenPGP output.

Comment: For those who stumble in here, the format of the Literal Data Packet, which it sounds like user1310492 is referring to, is not the same as the ASCII vs binary output for the PGP file.

Comment: Actually, it is pretty much [base64 with some checksum addition](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-6).